# a function to find which event occured for a table in Trigger

Tags: sql, events, if-statement, triggers, conditional-statements

I have a`Trigger`. I want have a condition in it, for example `IF(INSERT_EVENT OCCURED) then ...`

I don't know how write this condition?!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i

`IF ( INSERT EVENT OCCURRED )`

would be

`FOR INSERT AS`

Comment: can I use some `FOR ... AS` in one trigger?

Comment: Sure - anything after AS you want.. think of it as same "as" in stored procedure